# find printf what is correct format in crontab?

Tags: bash, cron, find, printf

i want to save a list of files and i want to do in cron but i dont know how to convert this command

```
echo $(find /tmp -type f -printf "%p||%s||||||") > /share/Public/serwer/test33.data
```

in terminal this command works ok but in cron is smothing wrong, file is empty, why?

i tried add slashes before variables %s %p

i tried many many other combinations:

```
echo $(find /tmp -type f -printf "%p||%s||||||") > /share/Public/serwer/test33.data
echo $(find /tmp -type f -printf "%p||%s||||||") > /share/Public/serwer/test32.data
echo $(find /tmp -type f) > $TMP_DIR/test31.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf \%p) > $TMP_DIR/test30.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf %p) > $TMP_DIR/test28.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f) > $TMP_DIR/test27.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "ab") > $TMP_DIR/test26.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "||") > $TMP_DIR/test25.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "%p||%s\r\n") > $TMP_DIR/test01.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "\%p||\%s\r\n") > $TMP_DIR/test02.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "\%p") > $TMP_DIR/test03.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "\%s") > $TMP_DIR/test04.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "\\%s") > $TMP_DIR/test05.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "\\%p") > $TMP_DIR/test06.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "\r\n") > $TMP_DIR/test07.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf) > $TMP_DIR/test10.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf) > $TMP_DIR/test11.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "%p") > $TMP_DIR/test12.data
echo $(find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "\%p") > $TMP_DIR/test13.data
echo `find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "%p"` > $TMP_DIR/test14.data
echo `find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "\\\\%p"` > $TMP_DIR/test15.data
echo `find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf \%p` > $TMP_DIR/test16.data
echo `find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf '\%p'` > $TMP_DIR/test17.data
echo `find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf '\\%p'` > $TMP_DIR/test18.data
echo `find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf '\\\%p'` > $TMP_DIR/test19.data
echo `find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf '\\\\%p'` > $TMP_DIR/test20.data
echo `find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf \%'s` > $TMP_DIR/test21.data
echo `find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf \%'p` > $TMP_DIR/test22.data
echo `find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf \%'p'` > $TMP_DIR/test23.data
echo `find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf \%'s'` > $TMP_DIR/test24.data
```

nothing work

Comment: Have you had a look at this?
https://www.stetic.com/developer/cronjob-linux-tutorial-und-crontab-syntax/

Comment: basic instruction about how to configure crontab?

Comment: you want to run your command inside the crontab right?

Comment: right, and if i dont add -printf parameter its run ok

Comment: Have you tried to use a script to save your statment? Then it'd look like:
* * * * * /usr/bin/script.sh >> /share/Public/serwer/test33.data

Comment: i reconfigure crontab and restart server in log nothing write, except my messages

Comment: Just curious, why do you `echo $(find ...) > file` instead of just `find ... > file`?

Comment: just habitually

Comment: @SławomirKudła You should consider changing your habits, then. If the substituted command outputs `echo` options (e.g. `-n`, `-e`...) the result will not be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This crontab entry should work :

```
* * * * * find /tmp -type f -printf "\%p||\%s||||||\n" > /share/Public/serwer/test33.data 2>/tmp/crontab.err
```

Comment: why add an escape character in front of '%', is there any references? thanks.

Comment: @Echo taken from man crontab: "Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input."

Answer (score 0):

i added full path to command find, now it works correctly

```
/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/.qpkg/Qapache/bin/find $BACKUP_DIR -type f -printf "%p||%s\r"
```

thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Philippe i do that and i have smothing like this:

```
find: unrecognized: -printf
BusyBox v1.24.1 (2021-09-23 02:31:15 CST) multi-call binary.

Usage: find [-HL] [PATH]... [OPTIONS] [ACTIONS]

Search for files and perform actions on them.
First failed action stops processing of current file.
Defaults: PATH is current directory, action is '-print'

    -L,-follow  Follow symlinks
    -H      ...on command line only
    -xdev       Don't descend directories on other filesystems
    -maxdepth N Descend at most N levels. -maxdepth 0 applies
            actions to command line arguments only
    -mindepth N Don't act on first N levels
    -depth      Act on directory *after* traversing it

Actions:
    ( ACTIONS ) Group actions for -o / -a
    ! ACT       Invert ACT's success/failure
    ACT1 [-a] ACT2  If ACT1 fails, stop, else do ACT2
    ACT1 -o ACT2    If ACT1 succeeds, stop, else do ACT2
            Note: -a has higher priority than -o
    -name PATTERN   Match file name (w/o directory name) to PATTERN
    -iname PATTERN  Case insensitive -name
    -path PATTERN   Match path to PATTERN
    -ipath PATTERN  Case insensitive -path
    -regex PATTERN  Match path to regex PATTERN
    -type X     File type is X (one of: f,d,l,b,c,...)
    -perm MASK  At least one mask bit (+MASK), all bits (-MASK),
            or exactly MASK bits are set in file's mode
    -mtime DAYS mtime is greater than (+N), less than (-N),
            or exactly N days in the past
    -mmin MINS  mtime is greater than (+N), less than (-N),
            or exactly N minutes in the past
    -newer FILE mtime is more recent than FILE's
    -inum N     File has inode number N
    -user NAME/ID   File is owned by given user
    -group NAME/ID  File is owned by given group
    -size N[bck]    File size is N (c:bytes,k:kbytes,b:512 bytes(def.))
            +/-N: file size is bigger/smaller than N
    -links N    Number of links is greater than (+N), less than (-N),
            or exactly N
    -prune      If current file is directory, don't descend into it
If none of the following actions is specified, -print is assumed
    -print      Print file name
    -print0     Print file name, NUL terminated
    -exec CMD ARG ; Run CMD with all instances of {} replaced by
            file name. Fails if CMD exits with nonzero
    -exec CMD ARG + Run CMD with {} replaced by list of file names
    -delete     Delete current file/directory. Turns on -depth option
```